# Ruby Gem Spreadsheet - Format Issue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, spreadsheet

I am writing out data to an Excel sheet, from another Excel sheet. However, the data for a column could look like any of the following:

- `$0.00`
- `The amount owed at time of service is $33`
- `20%`
- or an empty string.

My problem is that when I write it to the file, Excel is marking the column as "General" for formatting, and that strips off the `$` and `%` and makes it `0.2`. Is there a way to set the format to be just a plain string so that it will leave the data intact when I write to the spreadsheet?

I am new to Ruby, so if you see anything in the code that should be done another way please let me know.

Code Example:

```
def self.add_data(new_book_sheet, old_book_sheet)
  row_index = 9
  header_row = 0
  old_book_sheet.each do |row|
    if header_row > 0
      column_index = 0
      row.each do |column|
        new_book_sheet.row(row_index).insert(column_index, column)
        column_index += 1
      end
      row_index += 1
    end
    header_row = 1
  end
end
```

Comment: So if anyone knows how to make it read it in as a string and not "convert" it to a "number" that would be great. With my little ruby experience I tried to do this |column.to_s| but that just threw an error. By the time I am in the block if I output column.to_s it is to late the $ or the 20% has already changed to 0 or .2.

Comment: If you are using ruby spreadsheet gem, you can use Row#at method to get the raw values (without formatting to numbers). Look at http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/Spreadsheet/Row.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an apostrophe before the output and Excel will interpret it as text.  I tested the following in Excel (directly in a spreadsheet, not using the gem), and all were interpreted as strings:

- `'$0.00`
- `'The amount owed at time of service is $33`
- `'20%`
- `'`

Comment: Yes this did work in the excel file. However I figured out my real problem. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that when it is reading the data out of the original excel file if it is just a "number" type it is reading it that way so the $0.00 it is reading it as 0.
I thought the problem was with the writing of the data but it is actually when it reads the data.